# How to hide a specific button with the same class name

Tags: javascript, function

How can I write a function that hides a specific button using vanilla js?

```
<button class"btn">button 1 </button>
<button class"btn">button 2 </button>
<button class"btn">button 3 </button>
```

For example what I want is when I click button 2, button 1 and 3 will be hidden.

Comment: you need to write a clear question so you an answer. try to give more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector("button:nth-child(2)")` for getting 2nd button,  `addEventListener` and `style.display` for your requirement.

```js
var second = document.querySelector("button:nth-child(2)");
second.addEventListener("click", button2click);

function button2click() {
  var first = document.querySelector("button:nth-child(1)");
  var third = document.querySelector("button:nth-child(3)");
  first.style.display = 'none';
  third.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<button class"btn">button 1 </button>
<button class"btn">button 2 </button>
<button class"btn">button 3 </button>
```